# How to wait till a new promise is reolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to force the promise to wait till a broadcast is fired. so I referred to some posts in this website, and used the technique shown below in the code 
section.

but actually the the  **broadcastPromise** does not wait till it is resolved.

please provide a solution

**code**:

```
const promiseFunctions = {};
const broadcastPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  promiseFunctions.resolve = resolve;
  promiseFunctions.reject = reject;
});

broadcast() {
      promiseFunctions.resolve(broadcastValues);
}

return myMethod({
//fire the broadcast
..
})
.then(() => broadcastPromise) //this line must wait till the broadcast is fired and the value from it is resolved
.then(() => 
//do some processing on broadcastPromise
return value;)
```

Comment: What are you returning from `myMethod`?

Comment: As far as one can tell from the quoted code, that chain will indeed wait for the `broadcastPromise` to be resolved.  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Please post the code of `myMethod`. If it is the one responsible for firing the broadcast, you probably should not need that global `broadcastPromise` at all - just return the promise that you will later resolve.

Comment: That said, if the broadcast is being fired from *within* `myMethod`, the structure shown doesn't make a lot of sense. So we definitely need that MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code in question (`myMethod()`), you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Write your `broadcast()` function as a promise returning function, either as `async broadcast(){}` or make sure it return a promise.

Then, from your promise chain, `myMethod` is returning a promise. To "wait until a new promise is resolved", either:

a) Use `async function myMethod(){}` and simply await the `broadcast()` call.
or
b) Chain the broadcast inside the returned Promise of `myMethod()`